# Multicasting on guest Operating System

Tags: virtualization

I have 6 guest Operating Systems (windows server 2008) on a vmware 9.0
My host OS is Windows 8.1,
And GNS3 installed on the host OS, where I have my topology with 3 routers configure with multicast sparse mode.
I can ping successful between guest OS via the GNS3.
The issue now is, how do I configure each of these guest OS to do multicast and join multicast group? Both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: What would you do with this multicast group?

Comment: I want the 5 guest Operating Systems join to one or more multicast group, and the 6th to serve as the source of the traffic. This to enable the source to generate multicast traffics and send to this group